# Searching a sheet for value stored in a cell fails

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm an extreme novice in programming and am trying to work an assignment that keeps failing. My code searches a sheet(tab1) in Google sheets for a value that is in a cell in another sheet(tab2). For some reason, the search never finds the value. For simplicity I tested by changing the value that I'm looking for to a whole number, not a ".GetValue". I then had an if statement that would alert with message "Found" and "Not Found" if it wasnt found. The data is never found.

```
function editRecord(){

  var myGoogleSheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var shUserForm=myGoogleSheet.getSheetByName("Form");
  var datasheet=myGoogleSheet.getSheetByName("Records");
  var ui=SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var response=ui.alert("Submit", 'Do you want to submit your data?', ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
  var str=shUserForm.getRange("F7").getValue();
  var values=datasheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var valuesFound=false;

  if(response==ui.Button.NO){
    
      return;
  }
  
  for (var i=0;i<values.length;i++){

      if (values[i][1]==str){

      var iRow=i+1;
       
      datasheet.getDataRange(iRow,5).setValue(shUserForm.getDataRange("F15").getValue());
      datasheet.getDataRange(iRow,6).setValue(shUserForm.getDataRange("F17").getValue());
      datasheet.getDataRange(iRow,7).setValue(shUserForm.getDataRange("F19").getValue());

      ui.alert("Data updated.");
    
      shUserForm.getDataRange("F15").clearContent;
      shUserForm.getDataRange("F17").clearContent;
      shUserForm.getDataRange("F19").clearContent;
      shUserForm.getDataRange("F21").clearContent;
      shUserForm.getDataRange("F23").clearContent;
      shUserForm.getDataRange("F25").clearContent;

      valuesFound=true;

      return;
    }

    if (valuesFound==false){
      
      ui.alert("Your ID was not found.");
        
      return;

    }

  }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Modification points:

- I think that in your script, by `return` of `if (valuesFound==false){}`, when `values[i][1]==str` is `false`, the for loop is finished. By this, for example, when `values[i][1]==str` is `false` at the 1st row of `values`, the for loop is finished. I thought that this might be the reason of your issue.
- About `getDataRange(iRow, 5)` of `datasheet.getDataRange(iRow, 5)`, unfortunately, `getDataRange` has no arguments. I think that an error also occurs at this part.
- About `clearContent` of `shUserForm.getDataRange("F15").clearContent`, in this case, the method of `clearContent` is not run.

If you want to search the value, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script 1:

When your script is modified, it becomes as follows.

```js
function editRecord() {
  var myGoogleSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var shUserForm = myGoogleSheet.getSheetByName("Form");
  var datasheet = myGoogleSheet.getSheetByName("Records");
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var response = ui.alert("Submit", 'Do you want to submit your data?', ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
  var str = shUserForm.getRange("F7").getValue();
  var values = datasheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var valuesFound = false;
  if (response == ui.Button.NO) {
    return;
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    if (values[i][1] == str) {
      var iRow = i + 1;
      datasheet.getRange(iRow, 5).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("F15").getValue());
      datasheet.getRange(iRow, 6).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("F17").getValue());
      datasheet.getRange(iRow, 7).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("F19").getValue());
      ui.alert("Data updated.");
      shUserForm.getRange("F15").clearContent();
      shUserForm.getRange("F17").clearContent();
      shUserForm.getRange("F19").clearContent();
      shUserForm.getRange("F21").clearContent();
      shUserForm.getRange("F23").clearContent();
      shUserForm.getRange("F25").clearContent();
      valuesFound = true;
      return;
    }
  }
  if (valuesFound == false) {
    ui.alert("Your ID was not found.");
    return;
  }
}
```

#### Modified script 2:

I thought that in your script, `getValue` and `setValue` are used in the loop. In this case, the process cost will become high. So, as another modified script, how about the following modification?

```js
unction editRecord() {
  var myGoogleSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var shUserForm = myGoogleSheet.getSheetByName("Form");
  var datasheet = myGoogleSheet.getSheetByName("Records");
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var response = ui.alert("Submit", 'Do you want to submit your data?', ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
  var str = shUserForm.getRange("F7").getValue();
  if (response == ui.Button.NO) {
    return;
  }
  var res = datasheet.getRange("B1:B" + datasheet.getLastRow()).createTextFinder(str).matchEntireCell(true).findNext();
  if (!res) {
    ui.alert("Your ID was not found.");
    return;
  }
  var [[v1],,[v2],,[v3]] = shUserForm.getRange("F15:F19").getValues();
  datasheet.getRange(res.getRow(), 5, 1, 3).setValues([[v1, v2, v3]]);
  shUserForm.getRangeList(["F15","F17","F19","F21","F23","F25"]).clearContent();
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  ui.alert("Data updated.");
}
```

- In this sample, the value is searched using TextFinder. And, the cells are cleared using the RangeList.

#### References:

- [getRange(row, column)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer))
- [clearContent()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#clearContent())
- [createTextFinder(findText)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#createTextFinder(String))

Comment: Success, thank you :) Modified script 2 worked with a tweak while Modified script 1 didn't. The tweak was changing the "B1:B" to "A1:A". The data to search for is in column A.

I don't know why Modified script 1 never finds the data in the F7 cell. I moved things around to test with no luck. I put the column to search in Column B just in case that was where it was searching. "Data not found." I then changed the array in values from values[i][1] to values[i][0] as a test. "Data not found."

Comment: @RichardR Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. From your reply, you say `The data to search for is in column A.`. But in your script, you are checking the column "B". So I had thought that you wanted to search the column "B". This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for my poor skill again. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was able to successfully write the full script after getting this one problem solved. Your help was invaluable in me getting a good grade in the class.